# Lollipop Android ListView getting clipped

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-5.0-lollipop

I am displaying some info. within a `listView` with custom adapter.But getting last row clipped in `ListView`.The issue arises only in `lollipop devices` like `Moto G` with `lollipop` and so on.With other devices its perfect.

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/playerList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/upperContainer"
        android:divider="@color/white"
        android:dividerHeight="10dp"
        android:scrollbars="none"

        />
```

Theme:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"/>

  <style name="MyTheme" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
 </style>
```

Comment: Scroll down then.... what's wrong with that??

Comment: Exactly. Why don't you scroll down.

Comment: @MD Its clipping the last row.The image is to display the clipped part.Last row means the end of the listView

Comment: @RamandeepNanda Please read the question.The last row is clipped and only in devices containing lolipop.And Last row means the end of the listView

Comment: What theme do you use fir your activity?

Comment: @Delargo I have used @style/Theme.AppCompat.Light from 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'

Comment: @Delargo Also I have used SlidingMenu with AppCompact

Comment: What's the parent of list layout ? Can you try fill_parent instead of match_parent.

Comment: @RamandeepNanda Its already match_parent

Comment: @MD Thanks  figured it out!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was after Api 21 or greater the SystemUiVisibility is visible.Sliding menu has not included that to hide.So I hide it using below snippet.Added this into the Sliding menu init construtor.That's it :-)

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21)
        setSystemUiVisibility(SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```